# SQL Query a Table grouped by some columns but taking the first row ordered by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

With a summary table below

| CardNumber | Name | LastName | LastEntrance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Name1 | Lastname1 | 2021-12-01 18:00:00 |
| 123 | Name2 | Lastname2 | 2021-12-01 17:00:00 |
| 234 | Name3 | Lastname3 | 2021-12-01 10:00:00 |
| 234 | Name5 | Lastname5 | 2021-12-01 09:00:00 |
| 567 | Name4 | Lastname4 | 2021-12-01 16:00:00 |

I want to have a table with unique `CardNumber`, `Name`, `LastName` grouped rows with the most recent `LastEntrance` of. My result table should be:

| CardNumber | Name | LastName | LastEntrance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Name1 | Lastname1 | 2021-12-01 18:00:00 |
| 234 | Name3 | Lastname3 | 2021-12-01 10:00:00 |
| 567 | Name4 | Lastname4 | 2021-12-01 16:00:00 |

Could I query this table with a simple SQL query?

Comment: Post your query

Comment: [Check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: To keep the question simple I didn't share the whole thing. As soon as I try the proposed solutions, I'll return and update the question. Thanks for all answers.

Comment: @serkanz if the solution doesn't apply at 100%, I will suggest you make a new question, first because we try to make QA very specific for further use for others users, but second because you will get more attention than editing it with already 3 answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the logic of crossing with itself and compare every row with the another one if it's bigger. Then only show the crossed ones. No subqueries, more performance, more easy to read.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable t1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2
    ON (t1.CardNumber = t2.CardNumber 
         AND t1.Name = t2.Name          
         AND t1.LastName = t2.LastName
         AND t1.LastEntrance < t2.LastEntrance)
WHERE t2.CardNumber IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to find the `max(LastEntrance)` by employee to get the desired results

```
select * 
from cards cards1
where LastEntrance = (select Max(LastEntrance) 
                      from cards cards2
                      where cards1.CardNumber = cards2.CardNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to group by at all. since you just want to most recent you can do as below. By querying most recent LastEntrance from your table and using that in your main query.

```
Select t.CardNumber,t.Name,t.LastName,t.LastEntrance from tableX t
where t.LastEntrance= (select Max(a.LastEntrance) from tableX a where a.CardNumber=t.CardNumber)
order by t.CardNumber
```

[image]